# Accessing index in nested *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-container

This is a very peculiar problem for my project so if it is something dumb then please spare me.

I am building a dynamic table in Angular where each row is a word and Columns are the languages and each cell is the corresponding translation in that language.

So the problem is that I have to keep track of which table cell a user has clicked so that I can create or update the value of that cell.

The code is something like this:

```
    <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let data of data">

    <td contenteditable='true' (keyup.enter)="saveEntry($event)"  
    width="300px" height="40px" >{{data.key}}</td>

    <td *ngFor="let column of tableColumns;let j = index" 
      contenteditable='true'            
     (keyup.enter)="onRowClick($event, column.languageID,             
       data?.value[0]?.dictionaryEntryID)"                         

     (click)="TranslationClick($event,data.value[k].dictionaryID)">


   <ng-container *ngFor="let dataValue of data.value ;let k = index">

   <span *ngIf="column.languageID==dataValue.languageID">

   {{dataValue.translation}}</span>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="column.languageID!=dataValue.languageID">
    </span>
     </ng-container>
     </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Help needed : I need to get index k of the *ngFor in the ng-container in my 
       `TranslationClick` method like this :

```
 (click)="TranslationClick($event,data.value[k].dictionaryID)
```

I know that the `ng-container` *ngFor loop is created after the first but Is there any way I can get the index k of that cell before hand.

Or is there any other better way to keep track of the individual cells of the table?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access a template variable outside of the template where it is defined.

`k` can only be accessed within

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let dataValue of data.value ;let k = index">

   <span *ngIf="column.languageID==dataValue.languageID">

   {{dataValue.translation}}</span>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="column.languageID!=dataValue.languageID">
    </span>
   </ng-container>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to access value of that index without using that index as you mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @KIA With NgModel and NgModelOnChange

Comment: It's unclear to me what you try to accomplish. `k` ouside of above code (in my answer) is a set of numbers from 0 tp the length of `data.value`. What value do you expect `k` to have?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `k` will give me the index of the `data.value` and  which will give me the object at that index  or in other words the object at that particular cell of the table.

Comment: But which `k`? What would be a concrete value of `k` be where `data.value[k].dictionaryID` is executed?